# MetaData Schema and MetaData Values

Tags: sdl-tridion

Help me out..
I'm new to tridion. I want to know what is the purpose of creating metadata Schema and defining metadata values in the schema

Answer (score 3):

What Sudhakar added in his comment is true. You can add metadata schema to most objects in Tridion, but the true question is why. Metadata is used to "tag" or "classify" content. What that means? 
Well for example, you can tag your products with tags like "sport", "movies", "games" and then query with that criteria on content delivery side.

You can also add some information that can be used for other parts of the system, like some information regarding templating.

Comment: Indeed, classification of items is one use case. Many other use cases exist, though. Custom metadata is a very generic mechanism that can be used for all kinds of things; it completely depends on your implementation if and how you use it and what it means.

Comment: I agree. But for someone who is new to Tridion this is the easiest case to explain. :)

Answer (score 2):

Users can use the Metadata Schema you created to add metadata values to Publications, Folders, Virtual Folders, Structure Groups, Pages, Categories, Keywords, Component Templates and Page Templates.

If the Metadata Schema was created in a BluePrint Parent Publication, the Metadata Schema is shared to all Child Publications.

Please read full article [here](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-CE3B26AE-A039-433A-8829-F50A14C7E4CF)